# Adding a border to a CSS tringle made using borders

Tags: css

I have this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GSA5R/2/

Whereby i use the border property to create the triangle effect. However, how can i give the triangle a white border? If its already being used for the triangle!?

Comment: Well technically, as far as the browser is concerned, it's still a square. So you can't use something like `box-shadow`. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution that comes to me is to place another white triangle behind the gray one. But you need some extra markup, because you can't use `:after:after` :)

Example **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/hRsdg/)**. I used a `<span>` inside the `<a>` tag.

Comment: NB. This is the correct answer currently. But the CSS3 spec suggests that more sophisticated pseudo-element behaviour - e.g. nested pseudo-elements - will be supported in future browsers: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#nesting